# Select all items in listbox when updated via UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).IsInAsyncPostBack)
        {
            string id = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).AsyncPostBackSourceElementID;

            if (id == cboGroup.UniqueID)
            {
                foreach (ListItem i in lstTest.Items)
                    i.Selected = true;
            }
        }
}
```

This code runs when my cboGroup causes my UpdatePanel to refresh which has the lstTest in it and the data inside of it gets updated, but it does NOT select them all. How can I make it so when my UpdatePanel is finished refreshing all elements of the list box that it refreshed get selected?

[edit] I'm noticing now that at this point what's in the listbox is the previous values and not the new values I would need. So this seems to be before the listbox is filled with data (which is via a SqlDataSource) so it's probably overwriting this.

Comment: Is `lstTest` a child of the `UpdatePanel`?

Comment: Yes, lstTest is inside an UpdatePanel content template. Selecting something from a combo box triggers the updating of the UpdatePanel.

Comment: What is the `UpdateMode` of it? Make it `Conditional` and use `UpdatePanel1.Update()` to update it from codebehind.

Comment: The UpdateMode is already set to "Conditional". For getting it's data the ListBox is tied to an SqlDataSource and all that works fine. I'm just needing to have them all selected when it comes back to the user. I tried pnlTest.Update() after I run the selection code above, but no difference.

Comment: Is `pnlTest` the `UpdatePanel` of `lstTest`?

Comment: Yes sir. lstTest is inside pnlTest's content template.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to put my selection code in the list box's DataBound() event.

```
    protected void lstTest_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SelectAllTest();
    }
```